# What does "A list is any collection that implements the IList interface or its generic counterpart" mean?

Tags: xaml, generic-list

I'm reading a book on XAML. 
And I can't figure out what "its generic counterpart" mean in the following context. 
The term 'generic' always sounds confusing to me when it comes to learning computer language.

---

A list is any collection that implements the IList interface or its generic counterpart. For
example, the following XAML adds two items to a ListBox control whose Items property
is an ItemCollection that implements IList:

```
<ListBox xmlns=”http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation”>
<ListBox.Items>
    <ListBoxItem Content=”Item 1”/>
    <ListBoxItem Content=”Item 2”/>
</ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that the collection class implements one or both of these two interfaces:

- [System.Collections.IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ft6hw7.aspx)
- [System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)

See also [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)
.